# How to execute a file based on the mime type in Nautlius?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, mime-type

I can execute the file via terminal. But how can I tell Nautilus to do the same on double click?

[image: error on double-click]

[image: nautilus file permissions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add mime type associations in `$/.local/share/application/mimeapps.list` for current user. Sample snippet is here,

```
    [Added Associations]
    application/excel=planmaker-free18.desktop;
    application/mspowerpoint=presentations-free18.desktop;
    application/msword=textmaker-free18.desktop;
    application/ppt=presentations-free18.desktop;

   [Default Applications]
   text/html=google-chrome.desktop
   text/x-arduino=arduino-arduinoide.desktop
```

You have to first add new association it to `[Added Associations]` section and then add to `[Default Applications]` section to make default. For your type in question add `application/x-sharedlib=some-application.desktop` in both sections. Then save the file and try to open. May be you want to restart the **nautilus**.

If you want to make edits globally edit file in `/usr/share/application/default.list`

Comment: I'm aware of `mimeapps.list`. But it won't work for an executable

Comment: with which application do you need to open that file?

Comment: In terminal I would use `./`. But `bash` is unable to run it. So I don't think any application is capable of running it

Comment: Yes,Shared libraries cannot directly execute via terminal or any other application. I answered above question as general file type association .

Comment: Alright. So what I was missing was the `-c` option for `bash` in the `.desktop` file. Thanks!